Wie kürzt man "gentechnisch veränderte Linien" ("GV-Linien"?) korrekt ab?
Ich bin vor kurzer Zeit auf das Wort "GV-Linie" gestoßen, dass im Gentechnik-Kontext immer einmal wieder gebraucht wird, z. B. hier: https://cordis.europa.eu/article/id/25057-eu-approves-three-gm-maize-lines/de. Es steht für "gentechnisch veränderte Linien"
Allerdings herrscht große Uneinigkeit über die richtige Schreibweise, eine Google-Suchen weist auf 3 verschiedene Möglicheiten hin:

GV-Linie (wie verlinkt)
GV Linie (findet man auf Behördenseiten)
gv Linie (findet man auch auf Behördenseiten)

Welche Variante ist richtig? Oder sind alle 3 falsch/richtig?

"GV" ist i.Ü. eine gängige Abkürzung im Behördendeutsch für "Geschlechtsverkehr". Das ist dir hoffentlich bewußt.

Abgekürzt werden hier ja ein Attribut (veränderte) und ein dazu gehöriges Adverb (gentechnisch), also zwei klein und getrennt geschriebene Wörter. Deshalb wäre es erstmal eigentlich richtig, die Wörter getrennt abzukürzen, wie bei "u. a."  oder "z. B.":

g. v. Linien

Zur Schreibung siehe auch diese Frage: Wie schreibt man eine Abkürzung?
Der Wikipedia-Artikel Abkürzung ist auch recht ausführlich zur Schreibung.
Wenn die Wortfolge zu einem Begriff geworden ist, sich die Aussprache "Ge Vau Linie" durchgesetzt hat, und man betonen möchte, dass das ein Begriff ist, kann man m. E. durchaus auch zur Schreibung "GV-Linie" übergehen, die ja eigentlich für ein zusammengesetztes Substantiv stehen würde.
"GV Linie" und "gv Linie" sind Zwischenformen, die nicht in die deutsche Rechtschreibung passen.

Der Bindestrich verdeutlicht einen zusammenhängenden Begriff, ohne Leerzeichen bei Eigen- und Produktnamen, Abkürzungen und zusammengesetzten Substantiven. „GV-Linien“ (Anführungszeichen unten und oben im Deutschen) bildet einen (erfundenen?) Eigennamen und ist die bessere Wahl.

Anführungsstriche bilden keinen Eigennamen, sondern umschließen wörtliche Rede und Zitate.

Richtig. Anführungsstriche dienen notfalls auch zur Betonung oder Hervorhebung. Aber wenn schon, dann unten und oben.
